# Adding content after a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a webpage with a grid at the top, at the bottom I would like to include for elements but outside of the grid. When ever I try this nothing works and the form in part of the grid set up. What ever changes i make the size of the grid cell above it will change to match.

Here is my HTML code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TT284 EMA Question 1 Walking Events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="walkEvents.css" />
  </head>
    <header>  
        <figure id="logo">
            <img src="image goes here">
        </figure>   
    </header>   
    
    <body>
        <nav id="mainMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="walkEvents.html">Walking Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="otherEvents.html">Other Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="option3.html">Menu Option 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="option4.html">Menu Option 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="option5.html">Menu Option 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="loginPage.html">Sign Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
            
        
        <section class="gridInfo">
            <header id="pageTitle">
                <h1>Walking Events</h1>
            </header>
            <div>
                <h2>Planned Walks</h2>
                <p>List of planned walks will be here, starting with soonest first</p>          
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Walk History</h2>
                <p>List of previous walks, starting with the walk finished sooner</p>           
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Proposed Walks</h2>
                <p>List of proposed walks, sorted by date proposed with the oldest first</p>            
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Rejected Walks</h2>
                <p>List of previously rejected sorted by order of rejection</p>         
            </div>
            <div class="results">
                <h2>Search Results</h2>
                <p>Show results of search query</p>         
            </div>
    </body>     
            
    <footer>    
        <section class="forms">
            <div class="walkForm">
                <h2>Proposals</h2>
                <p id="text"><b>Name of Walk: </b><input class="form" type="text" name="nameOfWalk" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Date: </b><input class="form"  type="date" name="date" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Start time: </b><input class="form" type="time" name="startTime" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Meeting point: </b><input class="form"  type="text" name="meetingPoint" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Distance in miles: </b><input class="form" type="number" name="distance" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Notes: </b><input class="form"  type="text" name="notes" size="30" maxlength="300" /></p>
                <p><select name="status">
                <option value="proposed">Proposed</option>
                <option value="accepted">Accepted</option>                  
                <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>          
                </p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
            </div>
            <div class="searchForm">
                <h2>Search</h2>
                <p id="text"><b>Name of Walk: </b><input class="form" type="text" name="nameOfWalk" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Date: </b><input class="form"  type="date" name="date" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Start time: </b><input class="form" type="time" name="startTime" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Meeting point: </b><input class="form"  type="text" name="meetingPoint" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Distance in miles: </b><input class="form" type="number" name="distance" size="30" maxlength="30" /></p>
                <p id="text"><b>Notes: </b><input class="form"  type="text" name="notes" size="30" maxlength="300" /></p>
                <p><select name="status">
                <option value="proposed">Proposed</option>
                <option value="accepted">Accepted</option>                  
                <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>          
                </p>                                
                <p><input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />  <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear" /></p>
            </div>
        </section>  
    </footer>
  
  
  
 
</html>
```

CSS code below;

```
nav li {
    
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;   
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 25px
}

nav {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    text-align: center;
}

body section {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;    
    grid-template-rows: 50px 250px 250px 250px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    
}
    

section header {
    
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
} 

h1 {
    column-span: all;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}


body div {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 1rem;  
}


footer div {    
    border: none;
}   

#text, select{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit]{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=reset]{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
    

.results{
    column-span: all;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You can't use the same ID multiple times on the same page, use a class instead.

Comment: You seem to be applying `css-grid` to all `section` elements, is that not what you want?

Comment: I want the form inputs to be separate from the grid

Comment: Then don't apply `display:grid` to that section.

Comment: I change the display for that part but to no effect